# Running Selenium via jenkins on VM, screen size

Tags: selenium, testing, jenkins

I have a problem with running Selenium tests on VM. 
Tests are written under 1920x1080 resolution everything is OK until I run tests manually. Tests passes. The problem appear when I run tests through Jenkins. It's not a problem in my code.
I dont know why but screen resolution is much lower (1032, 776) - actually it's browser size. And that is the cause why buttons to test are not visible. Tests fails. 
Jenkins is opening by "Run slave agent via Java Web Start" and evertyhing works automatically on windows serwer. Old Selenium tests (written under lower resolution) works perfect. So the problem is closely related to screen size.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to set your screen size in the code? I have had to do that at some point when running tests headless. I set a low resolution, and then it worked.

Comment: you said you are executing your tests inside VM, usually VM itself have to be configured (one time configuration) to support big resolutions, did you did that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on Windows the following should work:

```py
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--headless");
options.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","\\path\\chromedriver.exe"); 
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```